# FFmepg Encode Video and Add Subtitles Not Working with Maps

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a video and add subtitles, but the subtitles are never added.

It only works if I remove `-map 0:v?` and `-map 0:a?`.

However I need maps so I can select the streams, such as `-map 0:a:1`.

```
ffmpeg -y 

-i "C:\Users\Matt\video.mp4" 
-i "C:\Users\Matt\subtitle.ass" 

-c:v libx264 
-preset medium -crf 37 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" 
-map 0:v? 
-map_chapters 0 

-c:s ass 
-map 0:s? 

-c:a ac3 
-b:a 320k 
-map 0:a? 

-map_metadata 0 

"C:\Users\Matt\video.mkv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtitles belong to input #1, so it would be `-map 1:s?`. Also, you don't need to transcode the subs since they're already ASS, so `-c:s copy`

Comment: When I try to use `srt` and `mpeg4` `avi` with `-map 1:s?` I get the error `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
Error initializing output stream 0:0`.

Comment: What does `mpeg4` `avi` refer to? Input or output file?

Comment: Input is `mp4`, Output is `avi`.

Comment: ffmpeg only supports `DivX XSUB` subs in AVI.

Comment: Ok? Your Q mentions MKV output, not AVI. See my comment above about AVI sub support.